# iOS16beta - CallKit - click the answer button can not presented to my app

Tags: ios, beta, callkit, ios16

when app unlocked: when the user answers the call, the app should be directly open, But on iOS16beta,  it didn't open my app di rectly，the suspension bar will not change or enter the app

then I found when i set CXCallUpdate.haveVideo=YES, it will not enter the app,
when I set CXCallUpdate.haveVideo=NO, it enters the app